# Call form.valid && submit in the same time

Tags: angular

I have a form that check valid form as first step and submit as second step but when I click on `creer` valid form works well but submit function doesn't work anymore I don't see anything in my console. I have already tried with onsubmit() only it works , I want to have both.
Any suggestion please ?

```js
onsubmit(){
  this.submitted=true;
  console.log("1");

  
  console.log("3");

  this.fnc.etat="en cours";
  this.analyseFncService.create(this.analysefnc);
   this.router.navigate(['/nav-quali/home-quali']);
   }
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)=" f.form.valid && onsubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Code Article</label>
      <select  class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && codeart.invalid }"  id="codeart" #codeart="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="fnc.codeart"   name="codeart">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let o of origine">{{o.codeart}}</option>
      </select>
      <div *ngIf="f.submitted && codeart.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="codeart.errors.required">codeart  is required</div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Libelle Article</label>
      <select type="text" class="form-control" id="libelle_art" required [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && libelle_art.invalid }" #libelle_art="ngModel"  [(ngModel)]="fnc.libelle_art" name="libelleart">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let o of origine">{{o.libelleart}}</option>
      </select>
      
      <div *ngIf="f.submitted && libelle_art.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="libelle_art.errors.required">Libelle is required</div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Créer</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: please remove the `angular-reactive-forms` tag as you are using template-driven form (with ngModel)

Comment: @GérômeGrignon done :)

Comment: you can add <form (ngSubmit)=" onsubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate> and then in onsubmit(form:ngForm) method add if(form.valid)..

Comment: what is this.registerForm?

Comment: @PanterP your suggestion will not stop me when I miss a field ,it s give me an error after  I submit

Comment: Remove `novalidate` since it is in fact a template validation

Comment: I removed it , but he still don"t call the function onsubmit()

Comment: the button's `type` is not set to `submit`, isn't that why the function doesn't get called?

Comment: no I can call the function if I remove f.form.valid

Comment: ah ok, sorry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your form element's `ngSubmit`:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onsubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
```

Then :

```
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Créer</button>
```

And in your TS part:

```
onsubmit(f){

  if (f.valid) { // here you check your form's validity

     this.submitted=true;
     console.log("1");
     console.log("3");
     this.fnc.etat="en cours";
     this.analyseFncService.create(this.analysefnc);
     this.router.navigate(['/nav-quali/home-quali']);

    }
 }
```

Comment: I did but I m forced to fill in all fields , and he don"t call onsubmit() same prblm

Comment: @HamzaNouri Updated the answer, try to pass the form in the onsubmit's func.

Comment: I already have other fields but they are not obligatory then when I do not fill them when I click on create nothing changes but when I fill all the fields it works, whereas I am not obliged to fill all the fields to click on create.

Comment: I do not see other fields in your question, there's two select options and both are marked `required`.

Comment: I suppressed required from other fields and it works thank u bro